# How to set ISO15693 data coding mode in Android?

Tags: android, nfc, rfid, iso-15693

The ISO 15693-2 specifies in section 7.2 that a VCD (reader) shall determine the data coding mode by appropriately encoding the Start-of-Frame (SOF).

How does one determine which of the two modes ("1 out of 256" and "1 out of 4") is used and how this can be changed?

PS: A pointer to Android source where this is done would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The NFC hardware in the Google Nexus devices does not support both modes, so you cannot configure this. It can actually only detect one card at a time.

Comment: I hear that the Nexus starts with "1 out of 256" and after detecting a 15693 device switches to "1 out of 4". Is this true? If so - how is it done?

Comment: The Nexus S (and other Android NFC-enabled phones) uses an NXP PN544 controller, which DS says supports both the "1 out of 256" and the "1 out of 4" data coding modes. 
Question: How does one select them programmatically?

Comment: You are right: the DS states that it supports both modes. I cannot find anything relating to this in the UM, though. I think you have to contact Customer Application Support to find out more.